# WebRequest slow even with null proxy

Tags: c#, performance, webrequest, system.net

I have the following code :

```
        private string DoWebRequest()
    {

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://thegamesdb.net/scripts/ajax_searchgame.php?searchterm=super+mario+64");
        request.Proxy = null;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

When I retreive the page with my webbrowser I get the answer in around 500ms. This url return simple json datas. But within the WebRequest with this method it takes around 45seconds.

When I look at Ants Performance Profiler the hot spot is the Create of the WebRequest and it looks like System.Net.Logging.get_On() is the cause... But I can't find a way to disable it.

Do you have already encouter this issue or any idea to help me ?

Comment: It might be an issue with your ISP.

Comment: How can it be as the download through my webbrowser is totally fine on the same machine and same connection ? :/

Comment: Also, as mentionned, the hot spot don't seems to be the download in itself.

Comment: On my PC, I get the result immediately.